# Open qml file referencing PyQt modules in QtCreator

Tags: python, qt, qml, pyqt5

I have a PyQt application with a QML file that imports a python module.
This works fine in the real application since I register the PyQt module in my main.py file before loading the QML file with:

```
QtQml.qmlRegisterType
```

But if I open the QML file in QtCreator to edit the GUI I get the error message "QML module not found".

How can I register or mock this Python module for use in QtCreator?